# Blocking two tables

Tags: postgresql, transaction

We have a simple postgres database:

```
book:
  id: primary key, integer
  title: varchar
  borrowed: boolean
  borrowed_by_user_id: foreign key user.id

user:
  id: primary key, integer
  name: varchar
  blocked: boolean
```

And now I would like to "borrow a book" `b` to a user `u`.

So, I make a transaction: (pseudocode)

Let's assume `READ COMMITED` isolation level.

```
b.id = 1, u.id = 1

begin transaction;
book = select for update book where id = 1
user = select user where id = 1 
if book.borrowed and not user.blocked: (*) 
   update book.borrowed = true, book.borrowed_by_user_id = 1
else:
   error -> book is taken or user is blocked

commit;
```

and it doesn't work. Because it allows to borrow a book to blocked user. When? For example if an admin would blocked user `u` after executing statement (*)  So, let's to repair it:

```
begin transaction;
book = select for update book where id = 1
user = select *for update* user where id = 1 
if book.borrowed and not user.blocked: (*) 
   update book.borrowed = true, book.borrowed_by_user_id = 1
else:
   error -> book is taken or user is blocked

commit;
```

But, it introduces a deadlock.

How to resolve problems like that?

Comment: The `select for update` seems unnecessary. Why don't you run `update book set borrowed = true, borrowed_by_user_id = 1 where id = 1 and not borrowed` right away? That will lock the row immediately without the possible race condition between the select and the update.

Comment: Your scenario describes a normal row lock, **not** a deadlock. A deadlock can only occur if two concurrent transactions lock at least two different resources. With two transactions locking the same (single) row, you can't get a deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

> and it doesn't work. Because it allows to borrow a book to blocked user. When? For example if an admin would blocked user u after executing statement (*)

On what basis do you say that this doesn't work?  If the admin blocked the user 1 billionth of a second **after** he checked out the book, the end result is that the book is checked out, and the user is blocked.  Is this wrong?  If so, how?  If this not wrong, then how can you be sure it isn't what happened, as opposed to the admin blocking him one billionth of a second **before** he checkout out the book?  If you cannot distinguish between these two orderings, then you have no basis to say that one of them is wrong.

Also, you say you are using READ COMMITTED isolation level.  This level explicitly allows for some anomalies to occur (although you haven't demonstrated any of them in your case).  If you want serializable, then use SERIALIZABLE.  That is why it exists.

> But, it introduces a deadlock.
>
> How to resolve problems like that?

Accept the deadlock and retry the transaction.

Also, please add a tag to indicate which language you are using.  It is not one I recognize.

Answer (score 0):

As a_horse_with_no_name mentioned, you can just do it all at once and simplify it

```
begin transaction;

update book set borrowed = true, borrowed_by_user_id = 1 where id = 1 and not borrowed

IF NOT ((select borrowed_by_user_id from book where id=1 and borrowed) = 1)
   error -> book is already taken by another user

commit;
```